# Normalizing difference between x_train /= 255.0 and x_train = x_train/255.0

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have some simple code, which loads the mnist data and normalizes the images.

```
    mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist

    (x_train, y_train),(x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
    x_train = x_train/255.0
    x_test = x_test/255.0
```

The code above works, however, if I try to use the shorthand for division, I get an error:

```
    mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist

    (x_train, y_train),(x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
    x_train /= 255.0
    x_test /= 255.0
```

The error is as follows:
`TypeError: ufunc 'true_divide' output (typecode 'd') could not be coerced to provided output parameter (typecode 'B') according to the casting rule ''same_kind''`

By playing around, I found a fix to it, in that typecasting `x_train` to `float32`, would get rid of the error, but I only stumbled upon the fix by accident. I don't understand why the code below fixes the issue

```
    mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist

    (x_train, y_train),(x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data(path=path)
    x_train = x_train.astype('float32')
    x_test = x_test.astype('float32')
    x_train /= 255.0
    x_test /= 255.0
```

Could someone explain what's happening here? Why do the two versions behave differently? Why's an explicit case required in the second instance but not the first?

 I didn't have much luck finding this behaviour documented anywhere.

Edit: I'm not sure what additional 'debugging details' I'm required to provide, since I've basically provided the entire code, the results as well as the details which I did not understand. I've also received no comments explaining why the question was closed, and/or what additional information is expected here. I would like some constructive criticism so as to atleast be able to ask the question in a better manner, if the present form isn't satisfactory by itself.

Comment: I didn't down vote, but sample data would be helpful. In addition to the code you have, how about printing out your `x_train` privately on your system and then making a very small sample dataframe of the same dtype that has the problem. Now keras is out of the picture and you can post an executable example that fails.

Comment: I think the problem is that `/=` means do the division and stuff back into the the array. But there was type conversion in the division so it can't go back in.

Comment: @tdelaney about the first comment, well the code as it stands of now, is executable by itself, and can be easily reproduced say on google colab, with just an additional import tensorflow statement. But I understand what you mean, and it makes sense so I went ahead and did that. So, what I figured is `x_train` and `x_test` are numpy ndarrays, of dtype `uint8`

Comment: @tdelaney about your second comment, well I still don't quite understand it. So then /= isn't a 'shorthand' for division and assignment? Technically, atleast?(Also, is this kind of behaviour documented somewhere?)
Or am I looking at it the wrong way? If you could post a detailed answer below, instead of a comment here, I'd also be glad to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Augmented division (`x_train /= 255.`) isn't just shorthand to regular division. It is implemented differently than regular division and has different intent.
Python objects have methods for implementing arithmetic functions.

- `/` is `__truediv__(self, other): ==> object`
- `/=` is `__itruediv__(self, other): ==> object`

Both return a result object (see
[Emulating numeric types](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types) in the python docs).

They are similar but have different intent when working with mutable objects like a list or a `numpy` array. `__truediv__` should not modify `self` whereas `__itruediv__` should. Implementations are free to ignore that, but generally `c = a / b` should not modify `a` but `a /= b` should modify `a`. When an object does not implement `__itruediv__`, python falls back to `__truediv__` - immutable objects typically don't implement the augmented version because they can't modify themselves.

In the case of numpy arrays, augmented division (`/=`) ends up calling [numpy.true_divide](https://numpy.org/doc/1.19/reference/generated/numpy.true_divide.html#numpy-true-divide). Since augmented division modifies the original array, it uses the `out` parameter to broadcast the result into the original object. This is where the error is - you can't broadcast a different datatype into an exiting array. Augmented division is the same as

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x_train = np.array([1,2,3], dtype='B')
>>> np.true_divide(x_train, 255., out=x_train)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: ufunc 'true_divide' output (typecode 'd') could not be coerced to provided output parameter (typecode 'B') according to the casting rule ''same_kind''
```

where as standard division is the same as

```
>>> x_train = np.array([1,2,3], dtype='B')
>>> foo = np.true_divide(x_train, 255.)
>>> x_train = foo
```

In your case, the differences in the division isn't really a bug. Since your operation creates a different type, numpy needs to allocate a differently sized chunk of memory to hold it. You can either stick with non-augmented division or pre-convert the array like you did with float32. They are both reasonable approaches. The trick with the augmented operators is to note that they broadcast a result back to the original array and have all of the restrictions of the broadcast.

Comment: Excellent answer, very well explained! Thanks. Just a thing, so the i in __itruediv__ actually stands for inplace, correct?

Comment: Yes, but its a bit misleading. Python uses the return value from `__itruediv__` to rebind the variable. So its "inplace" as far as the variable is concerned. But the variable may in fact be bound to a different object completely. Consider `foo = 1000` followed by `foo /= 3`. `foo` is now bound to a float that was returned by `int.__itruediv__`.

Comment: Ah, I see how it can be misleading. So it's functionally inplace, ie the end result is still a rebound variable to the intended value, except that it's not what is usually meant by inplace conventionally, where the operation is done on the object itself. Here, we could have an entirely different object. That makes sense, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to change type to `float32` you can do this:

```
mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist

(x_train, y_train),(x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
div = x_train / 255.0
x_train = div
```